# Error with figure and subfigure

Tags: floats

While trying out following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp₁.png}
    \caption{image1}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp₂.png}
    \caption{image2}
    \label{fig:2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}\quad
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp₃.png}
    \caption{image3}
    \label{fig:3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \medskip

  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp₄.png}
    \caption{image4}
    \label{fig:4}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp₅.png}
    \caption{image5}
    \label{fig:5}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{imp₆.png}
    \caption{image6}
    \label{fig:6}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Fasi del processo di impregnazione}
  \label{fig:images}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

the following error pops up

`LaTeX Error: Unknown float option`H'. [\begin{figure}[H]]`

Any suggestions are welcome

I need to put six photographs in a journal like

```
                                    photo1

                      photo2                    photo3

               photo4         photo5          photo6   and so on
```

The photos will be connected with lines from photo1 downwards

How can I do it?

Comment: The `H` specifier is defined by the `float` package.

Comment: Using the `H` placement specifier almost always causes far more trouble than it's worth. Don't use it. Use `[ht!]` instead.

Comment: Your write-up is quite confusing, I'm afraid: At one point, you mention wanting to place 6 images, but you also provide a diagram which suggests you need to place 7 images, in a 1-2-4 order. Which objective are you trying to pursue?